# R: What's the right way to add an interaction term in lm()?

Tags: r, regression

I'm working with the Carseats data. I'm making a model to predict the sales of Carseats and I'd like to make an interaction term with Price and Competitor Price.

Is it as simple as

```
lm(Sales~Price*CompPrice,data=Carseats)
```

I know it's important to include the original predictors individually, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is as simple! An equivalent but more explicit way of specifying the same model you did is as follows:

```
lm(Sales ~ Price + CompPrice + Price:CompPrice,data=Carseats)
```

The underlying model fitted by lm will be:

```
Sales = beta0 + beta1xPrice + beta2xCompPrice + beta3xPricexCompPrice + epsilon  (*)
```

Model (*) allows the effect of Price on Sales to depend on CompPrice:

```
Sales = beta0 + (beta1 + beta3xCompPrice)xPrice + beta2xCompPrice + epsilon
```

Indeed, the slope of Price depends on CompPrice.

Model (*) also allows the effect of CompPrice on Sales to depend on Price:

```
Sales = beta0 + beta1xPrice + (beta2 + beta3xPrice)xCompPrice + epsilon
```

Here, epsilon is an unknown (random) error term and Price and CompPrice are assumed to be continuous predictors.

Comment: Woot! And, that means a regression with all the terms + an interaction is lm(Sales ~. Price*CompPrice,data=Carseats)

Comment: And then, if Price and CompPrice are statsig but Price:CompPrice is not - does that mean their interaction doesn't explain variance in Y?

Comment: In principle, the answer to your second comment is yes. But tests of interactions can have low power - some people perform them by relaxing the significance level to guard against this (e.g., increase the significance level from 0.05 to 0.10).